# Dijkstra shortest path yields unintuitive results

Tags: graphs, shortest-path, weighted-graphs

Considering the following nodes with edge weights in red, Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm seems to return incorrect results, at least by the definition of the steps on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Algorithm). By those rules, the distance from `0` to `2` will be calculated by passing through `1` instead of `3`.

The final distances (from `0`) would come out to:

`0` -> 0

`1` -> 0.2

`2` -> 1000.2

`3` -> 0.5

The weights in this case are bi-directional but I don't see a way for information of the connection between `2` and `3` to ever affect the final distance between `0` and `2`. Am I missing something about the limitations of this algorithm on this type of graph or are the steps listed incorrect?

[image: example cycle]

Comment: In which order do you evaluate the nodes? What exactly do you do/get evaluating node 3?

Comment: @greybeard I misunderstood which way to propagate the current node from the instructions. I was originally taking the neighbor that had the lowest tentative distance and following a path from `0` -> `1` -> `2` -> `3`. Node `3` would have a distance of 0.5 since it was one of the first values I calculated and is much lower than 1000.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the wikipedia article you linked, the *final* distance is only computed when the node is visited (step 6). The *tentative* distance is (re)calculated each time to visit a parent of a node, and overwritten if it's smaller (step 3).

So in your example,

1. We visit node 0.  We set tentative(1) = 0.2, tentative(3) = 0.5
2. We visit node 1, since it has the smallest tentative distance. We set tentative(2) = 1000.2
3. We visit node 3.  Since 0.6 < 1000.2, we set tentative(2) = 0.6
4. We visit node 2.  Its final distance is tentative(2), which is currently 0.6

Comment: Oh, I clearly misunderstood step 6. It means the lowest global distance, not the distance relative to the current node! This was extremely helpful. Thanks!